# Firebase: Error (auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, passwords, .env

[image: here is error messages and error codes]

Even my api key is true and the configurations are same as firebase credentials.
If u know can u explain what can be wrong about my configurations or codes...

```
`(const handleLogin=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          console.log("signed in") 
            const user = userCredential.user;
            navitage("/")
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode);//line 24
          console.log(error);//line 25
          console.log(errorMessage);
          setError(true);
        });
  }
```

```
      `  <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <h1>Login</h1>
            <input type="email" placeholder="email" onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <button >Login</button>
            {error && <span>Wrong Password or Email. Try Again!</span>}
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone facing this issue that hasn't been able to solve it, one slight overlook I did (which resulted in an hour of debugging), was that, when I put my variables in a .env file, I accidentally added a comma (",") after each line:

```
          VITE_API_KEY="AIzaSyAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXjILO32ZDxRKY",
          VITE_AUTHDOMAIN="myproject.firebaseapp.com",
          VITE_PROJECT_ID="myproject",
          VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET="myproject.appspot.com",
          VITE_APP_ID="971123072180"
```

Remove those commas.
Basic mistake, but also quite easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/auth"


 const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId:process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID
})

export const auth = app.auth;
export default app
```

That is the best code for firebase authorization